# Is it possible to set auto-activation triggers for Xtend and other Xtext-generated languages?

Tags: eclipse, xtext, xtend, content-assist

In Eclipse, we can trigger Content-Assist automatically for Java for a given of characters, but I noticed that there is no such option in the Xtext generated languages or Xtend. Is it possible to set auto-activation triggers for these languages other than the default `Ctrl + Space`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to a string binding named `XtextContentAssistProcessor.COMPLETION_AUTO_ACTIVATION_CHARS` as described here: https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/xtext-content-assist-auto-activation/

Comment: The dependency injection setup with Guice really makes things easy!

Comment: This site is no longer active, can you please paste the relevant content in the post?

Comment: https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/09/19/xtext-content-assist-auto-activation.html